# How to create this type of design with working slider?

Tags: flutter

[[image]]

Please Help to create this design with slider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a package like `audio_waveforms` in flutter.
https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms

I haven't tested it. Although it looks like it can do the job.